# Use the current tags about categories of web applications as "default" tags for "untagged" questions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-clean-up

This is pointed to the Web Application members that review first posts and participated on tag cleaning efforts.

When a tag used on a single question reach certain age it is automatically deleted and replaced by [untagged](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). From time to time someone replaces this tag by a new tag but it later is deleted that deleted the previous tag.

Stack Overflow has the tag [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) that can be used when there is not a more specific tag like [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) or [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets).

My suggestion is that instead of creating a new tag for a web application that we aren't sure that there are Web Applications members that might answer that question, add and already exising "generic" tag like those listed below. (below of them is the current tag's excerpt)

- [chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat)

  > Where people connect or talk via real-time text or video messaging
- [cms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cms)

  > Content Management Systems allow people to update a site without the need for programming knowledge
- [crm](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crm)

  > Customer Relationship Management - a widely implemented strategy for managing a company’s interactions with customers, clients and sales prospects
- [search-engine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engine)

  > A tool designed to search for information on the World Wide Web and FTP servers.

When we reach concensus on this the next step could be to analyse what is happening with the above tags, one by one. In the mean time, if you decide to create a new tag add to it the usage guidelines (tag excerpt)

Related

- [Let's clean up some meta tags](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2696/88163)
- [The Web Application Nursery](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3803/88163)
- [In the context of Web Applications, which are the tags that are not specific to a web application that are not meta-tags?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3986/88163)
- [Tag Excerpt (guidance) improvement project](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4028/88163)
- [Do we need [social-networks]?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4321/88163)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tags that are essentially 'parent tags' or groups of existing tags that represent a single web application could avoid ending up with many [untagged](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions, so I'm not necessarily opposed to that. Some things that need to be considered:

- What happens if a web application does not fall into one of those categories?
- What do we do with suggested edits who only add, say, the [chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat) tag to a question tagged [whatsapp](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp)?

The alternative is not to change the tagging practice, but encourage users to write excerpts for new tags, even if it's just

> For questions about the [search engine / online chat platform / ...] [NAME], available at [DOMAIN].

I [once wrote a SEDE query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370137/295232) to detect tags which are about to disappear. [Running it now for Web Applications](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1450571/roomba-period-for-single-use-tags) show two tags which are about to disappear; the [tag pruning script runs only once a month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341923/295232) so that's why they're not gone yet.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your great contribution. I agree that there are still several things to consider. Also I agree that the ideal "solution" is that more people help to main tags that are worthy to keep. In the mean time I think that we could add a comment to the quetion or this answer for each case worthy to be shared and if it needs to be discussed create a new question or point people to a chat room. One of the outcomes could be to have ideas to improve this question, i.e. we could add more tags, find effective ways to encourage people to participate more.